# Hide comments to view the question

Tags: feature-request, comment, answers, user-interface

Is it possible to have a button hide comments (or something like that) in order to see the question when we write the answer?

When you write the answer it's often useful to see the question to have the same notations, or to be sure you get the definitions right ... It often happens that multiple comment (and answers) prevent you to see the question when you type the answer and force scrolling up and down (and I'm lazy ...).

Or may be a small view of the question above the "Your answer" box.

Sorry if it already have been discussed (or if it seems stupid :S)

Comment: This sounds like a useful feature. What I sometimes do is open the same page in two windows side-by-side, so I can scroll one to show the question and write my answer in the other.

Comment: Good idea. I sometimes have to copy part of a question to my answer to make sure to use similar notation, and get the numbers right. Nuisance.

Comment: Of course you can also open the answer in two tabs of your browser (or two windows - whichever you prefer). Then you do not need to scroll, only switch between the two windoews/tabs. If you have large enough monitor, maybe you can fit the two browser windows side by side. (Or if you have two monitors.)

Comment: How about bringing the answer box up over the comments section? Would this be possible? Since a hide-comment-button seems to be out of reach at the moment?!